# Does a event-component in Koala-Framework exist?

Tags: php, koala-framework

I'm developing a website with koala-framework and need to implement a component to handle events (or appointment).

It should list the next event at top, past events shouldn't be shown. Configuration happens in backend centralised.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Kwc_Events_Directory_Component`, that does exaclty what you need.